# Member Import XML join_date Format

Tags: import, xml

I'm exporting member data as xml from one site to another using [Export It](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/export-it).

When I import the xml via the EE Member Import Utility the 'Join Date' for each imported member is '0'.

The join_date format in the exported xml is:

```
<join_date>Jun 09, 2011, 07:46:04AM</join_date>
```

1. Is this incorrect?
2. Does it matter that the Join Date is 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `join_date` in ExpressionEngine is generally formatted as a UNIX timestamp and looks something like

```
field     type length value
join_date  INT  10    1118111578
```

It looks like your date is being converted to a human readable format on export, but you need to keep it as a UNIX Timestamp, for it to get stored properly.

I can't say, how much trouble maybe caused by the lack of a join_date or a join_date of 0. Anything that uses the `join_date` to calculate or display would be boinked, but in our installs, the join_date isn't used that much. Just to look-up when we added someone, if the were giving control panel access. So someone else would need to chime in on that component.

I believe [Export It](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/export-it) was designed to make your export Excel compatible, which is different from exporting data and re-importing it back into EE.

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful. I'm now trying out AJW Export to get the member data - even after a quick play I can get the UNIX Timestamp for the join_date!

Comment: Excellent. I've had Andrew Weaver's products save my bacon a number of times. Glad AJW Export could help you.